# jQuery Zoom Plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

My issue is that I'm making a zoom plug in jQuery. The situation is that when I click on smaller picture it gets popup where I can scroll the picture means that i can change its width height on scroll dynamically and can move it means i can change its left n top position dynamically... my problem is that when picture gets popup, moving effect starts but I want to start moving effect after scrolling once? Can anybody help?

Comment: You should try rephrasing that question - after three readings I still quite get what you're saying. Posting some code or link can also help to illustrate your problem.

Comment: can you add portion of code you are getting problem. is moving image is working on click but you want on scroll?

Comment: Frankly, I have no idea what you're describing. Please have someone rephrase it for you that speaks proper English.